# How to get the bounding rectangle of the rectangle drawn in the ArcGIS using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I am trying to draw the rectangle in the map and get the Rectangle bounds from it. I am able to draw it but I am not getting the rectangle bounds. I have followed this url :[Follow URL](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/How_to_draw_a_rectangle_on_the_screen/00010000047r000000/)

And my code as :

```c#
private bool isRectangleDrawn = false;
  public void DrawRectangle2(IActiveView activeView)
  {
     if (activeView == null)
     {
        return;
  }

   IScreenDisplay screenDisplay = activeView.ScreenDisplay;
   screenDisplay.StartDrawing(screenDisplay.hDC, (System.Int16)
   esriScreenCache.esriNoScreenCache);
   IRgbColor rgbColor = new RgbColor();
   rgbColor.Red = 255;

   ESRI.ArcGIS.Display.IColor color = rgbColor;
   ISimpleFillSymbol simpleFillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
   simpleFillSymbol.Color = color;

   ISymbol symbol = simpleFillSymbol as ISymbol;
   IRubberBand rubberBand = new RubberEnvelope();
   IGeometry geometry = rubberBand.TrackNew(screenDisplay, symbol);
   screenDisplay.SetSymbol(symbol);
   screenDisplay.DrawRectangle(geometry as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IEnvelope);
  isRectangleDrawn = true;
  screenDisplay.FinishDrawing();
}
```

I am not sure from where I will get the Rectangle bounds of this Rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created your polygon via the rubberband tracknew method and assigned it to the object `geometry`. You simply need to call the property [Envelope](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IGeometry_Envelope.htm) to return the bounding rectangle or "envelope" of your polygon.

Comment: Can you please rewrite the code which you are trying to tell me !! Thanks for your effort

Comment: How to set geometry on Envelop. I am not getting that!!